# Profiling the Spark Analyzer: how to access the QueryPlanningTracker for a pyspark query?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, profiling

Any Spark & Py4J gurus available to explain how to reliably access Spark's java objects and variables from the Python side of pyspark? Specifically, how to access the data in Spark's [QueryPlanningTracker](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0494dc90af48ce7da0625485a4dc6917a244d580/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/QueryPlanningTracker.scala) from python?

**Details**

I am trying to profile a *creating* a pyspark dataframe (`df = spark_session.sql(thousand_line_query)`). Not running the query. Just creating the dataframe so I can inspect its schema. Merely waiting for the return from that `.sql()` call which initializes the dataframe with no data takes a long time (10-30 seconds). I have tracked the slow steps to [Spark's Analyzer](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/Analyzer.scala) stage. Logging (below) suggests Spark is recomputing the same sub-query too many times, so I'm trying to dig in and see what is going on by profiling Spark's work on my query. I tried to methods from  a number of articles for profiling the Spark Optimizer stage for executing queries (e.g. Luca Canali's [sparkMeasure](https://github.com/LucaCanali/sparkMeasure), Rose Toomey's [Care and Feeding of Catalyst Optimizer](https://databricks.com/session_na20/care-and-feeding-of-catalyst-optimizer)). But I have found no guide that focuses on profiling the Spark Analyzer stage that runs before the Optimizer stage. (Hence I also include extra details below on what I've found that others may find helpful.)

Reading Spark's Scala sourcecode, I see [the `Analyzer` is a `RuleExecutor`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/Analyzer.scala#L186), and `RuleExecutor`s [have a QueryPlanningTracker](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/rules/RuleExecutor.scala#L21) which seems to record details on each invocation of each Analyzer Rule that Spark runs, specifically to allow a person to reconstruct a timeline of what the analyzer is doing for a single query.

However, I cannot seem to access the data in the Analyzer's QueryPlanningTracker from python. I would like to be able to retrieve a `QueryPlanningTracker` java object with the full details of the run of one query, and to inspect what fields & methods are available on the Python code. Any advice?

**Examples**

In python using `pyspark`, request a dataframe for my 1,000-line query and find it is slow:

```
query_sql = 'SELECT ... <long query here>
spark_df = spark_session.sql(query_sql) # takes 10-30 seconds
```

Turn on copious logging, rerun query above, look at output & see the slow steps all mention the `PlanCheckLogger` which is in the Spark Analyzer. Also access Spark's RuleExecutor to see how much time is used by each rule & which rules are not effective:

```
spark_session.sparkContext.setLogLevel('ALL')
rule_executor = spark_session._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor
rule_executor.resetMetrics()
spark_df = spark_session.sql(query_sql)  # logs 10,000+ lines of output, lines with keyword `PlanChangeLogger` give timestamps showing the slow steps are in the Analyzer, but not the order of steps that occur
print(rule_executor.dumpTimeSpent())  # prints Analyzer rules that ran, how much time was 'effective' for each rule, but no specifics on order of rules run, no details on why rules took up a lot of time but were not effective.
```

Next: Try (unsuccessfully) to access Spark's QueryPlanningTracker data to drill down to a timeline of rules run, how long each call to each rule took, and any other specifics I can get:

```
tracker = spark_session._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker
## Use some call here to show data contents of the tracker; which currently gives E.g. intitial exploration: 
tracker.measurePhase.topRulesByTime(10)
*** TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable ....
```

The above is one example; The tracker code suggests it has other methods & fields I could use, however I do not see how to access those nor how to inspect  from Python to see what methods & fields are available, so it is just trial & error from reading Spark's github repository ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
>>> df = spark.range(1000).selectExpr("count(*)")

>>> tracker = df._jdf.queryExecution().tracker()
>>> print(tracker)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker@5702d8be

>>> print(tracker.topRulesByTime(10))
Stream((org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions,RuleSummary(27004600, 2, 1)), ?)
```

I'm not sure what kinds of info you need. But if you want to know query plan generated. You can use `df.explain()`

Comment: Thanks; that helps but I just a summary of one rule, rather than detail on each rule invocation:  

`
    df = spark_session.sql(sql_clause)
    tracker = df._jdf.queryExecution().tracker()
    breakpoint()
    (Pdb) print(tracker)
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker@23d90c60
    (Pdb) print(tracker.topRulesByTime(10))Stream((org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences,RuleSummary(3514149520, 23, 18)), ?)
    (Pdb)
`


I'm trying to show a timeline of each rule invocation, rule run time, and rule arguments.